# Is this the good way to implement pagination in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to implement pagination for one of my tables. On the frontend, I want to show 50 rows initially and the next 50 as a user moves to the next pages. To achieve this I am using below steps:-

1. Execute query job
2. Retrieve jobid
3. Execute getQueryResults with that jobid and retrieve result and
   page_token
4. If page_token null - you done, otherwise continue with next step
5. Execute getQueryResults (still with jobid from #2) and retrieve
   result and page_token Jump to step #4

Below is the actual code that I have written to achieve this and it's working fine in development.

```
let options = token ? { 'pageToken': token, 'maxResults': maxRows } : { 'maxResults': maxRows };
  if (!token) {
    bigqueryClient.createQueryJob(query).then(function(data) {
      const job = data[0];
      return job.getQueryResults({ 'maxResults': maxRows });
    }).then(function(data) {
      if (data[1]) {
        return res.json({ token: data[1]['pageToken'], rows: data[0], totalRows: data[2]['totalRows'] });
      } else {
        return res.json({ rows: data[0] });
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      log.error(e);
      return res.status(500).json({
        e: e.message
      });
    });
  } else {
    const job = bigqueryClient.job(jobId);
    job.getQueryResults(options)
    .then(function(data) {
      if (data[1]) {
        return res.json({ token: data[1]['pageToken'], rows: data[0] });
      } else {
        return res.json({ rows: data[0] });
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      log.error(e);
      return res.status(500).json({
        e: e.message
      });
    });
  }
```

Also, I am canceling the previous jobs before creating a new one for the same user. 
Right now I am skeptical about how would jobs affect the Database performance when 1000's of users simultaneously start using it. Let me know if this is a correct way or I can use a different approach.

Comment: Do you really want to plug BigQuery in your Front end? What are you displaying? There is lot of data?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, we can have lots of calls for a client. Can you tell me is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first feeling is that you don't use the correct tool for your app. BigQuery is an awesome tool for analytics and for scanning petabyte of data. And it has 1 default: query warm up is long: about 1s not compressible.

That's why, I don't recommend BigQuery for a front end application. Imagine: click on a button, wait 1s, another click, another seconde,... Awful! Cloud SQL is the most relevant for this. Extract a subset of data from BigQuery and load them into Cloud SQL. The the users query only the Cloud SQL data.

The additional benefit of this pattern is the cost: Indeed, you told that a client can perform a lot of request. With BigQuery you pay the quantity of data that you scan in your query (and not the quantity that you read and return). Of course, if your query is in cache, you won't pay again, but, anyway, I still don't recommend you to use directly BigQuery in your app except if your use case is very specific and need it.

Comment: I also think the same will ask our team lead to having a 2nd thought.

Comment: Can you comment on my implementation? Does creating too many jobs have any negative impact on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery is fine for a front-end application provided it has been implemented securely and also correctly in terms of managing data usage and pagination. See this [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery). I'm the author.

Around a second delay (common when starting new query), less than a second delay (when paginating through existing query) and no delay (when paginating through already fetched data pages) are not a problem for many people doing research including scientists, analysts, auditors etc. They know one of the differences between data mining/research and online shopping are small delays :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you comment on my implementation? Does creating too many jobs have any negative impact on the backend.

Comment: At first glance there is no data usage control and error handling is insufficient. For example, BQ can return `jobComplete` flag (which you don't check) set to false indicating a timeout. Your error handling code won't pick it up. Maybe there are other issues, I'd suggest comparing your snippet with the implementation in my project. BQ has a documented limit of 100 queries on the count of concurrent queries (and therefore jobs), it's also mentioned in project's README.

Comment: We have dropped the idea of using a job for pagination. We are going with traditional Limit and Offset.

Comment: The other way of saying it: you decided not to use native BQ pagination and will be implementing it yourselves with traditional Limit and Offset.